# If a Borel $\sigma$-algebra is genertated by a collection, then the collection is closed under unions?

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

The question is:

Let $\left(M,\sigma\left(\tau\right),\mu\right)$ a measurable space with $\mu$  a probability.

If   $\sigma\left(\tau\right)$ is a Borel $\sigma$-algebra  such that is genertated by a collection $\mathcal{B}\subseteq\sigma\left(\tau\right)$, then $\mathcal{B}$  is closed under unions?

If the elements of  $\mathcal{B}$ are open, change the situation?

I try to find a contraexmple but I have not succeeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $M=\{1,2\}$ endowed with the discrete topology, the collection $\mathcal B:=\{\{1\} ,\{2\}\} $ generates the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and is not closed by unions.

Answer (score 0):

What if the collection is the set of all bounded open intervals on the real line?